# How to split a one word string in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

for example, if the string is "Nikki",

then how can I split it into "N", "i", "k", "k", "i"

**help pls**

Comment: ```[i for i in 'Nikki']``` also works! Check out Python documents about [str](https://docs.python.org/ko/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just construct a `list` using the string

```
>>> list('Nikki')
['N', 'i', 'k', 'k', 'i']
```

Although for what it's worth, a list of `chr` is functionally equivalent to just iterating directly through the `str` itself. In other words

```
for letter in 'Nikki':
```

will work, as will anything relying on a [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range).